# remove browser.sleep() from methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

Currently i am writing e2e tests using protractor for upload files. I have made methods in which i add file to container and after click upload button files are uploaded.
My page object file methods:

```js
    addCustom() {
       const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pathCustom');
       elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(0).sendKeys(absolutePath);
       browser.sleep(500);
    }

    addProd() {
       const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'pathProd');
       elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(1).sendKeys(absolutePath);
       browser.sleep(500);
    }

    addOrders() {
       const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pathOrders');
       elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(2).sendKeys(absolutePath);
       browser.sleep(500);
    }
```

In spec file i run test:

```js
it('should upload three .csv files', (done) => {
        let upload = new UploadPageObjects();
        upload.addCustom();
        upload.addProd();
        upload.addOrders();
        upload.upload();
        done();
        expect(upload.confirmMessage.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    });
```

If I remove browser.sleep() from methods when performing tests:

[Three files added in one container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCNX2.jpg)

Is there way to remove browser.sleep() from methods and avoid misbehavior?

```js
    upload() {
        button = element.by(css('#upload-button');
        browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(button), timeout);
        button.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
    }
```

Comment: This seems to me like its more of an issue with your css selector. Would it be possible to do something like `customer uploadCssSelector` and `product uploadCssSelector` instead of `uploadCssSelector.get(1)` and `uploadCssSelector.get(2)`?

Comment: could you show the code for "upload.upload()" @perivoje

Comment: upload() {browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(elem.by(css("#upload-button")), timeout);
    selector.click();
    browser.waitForAngular();}

Comment: @BenMohorc I thought also that it can be related to ElementArrayFinder, but I have added id-s but without success.

Answer (score 0):

this is expected due to asynchronous executions. This can be resolved with promises, I suppose. Can you please try this snippet

```
addCustom() {
             return new Promise((resolve, reject)={
           const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pathCustom');
           elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(0).sendKeys(absolutePath);
           // browser.sleep(500);
           });
    }

    addProd() {
             return new Promise((resolve, reject)={
           const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'pathProd');
           elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(1).sendKeys(absolutePath);
           // browser.sleep(500);
            });
    }

    addOrders() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject)={
           const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'pathOrders');
           elem.all(by.css('csslocator').get(2).sendKeys(absolutePath);
           // browser.sleep(500);
            }); 
    }
```

And update spec as below :

```
it('should upload three .csv files', (done) => {
        let upload = new UploadPageObjects();
        upload.addCustom().then(()=>{
            upload.addProd().then(()=>{
                upload.addOrders().then(()=>{
                    upload.upload();
                    done();
                    expect(upload.confirmMessage.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
                });
            });
        });
 });
```

Once the addCustom promise resolved, addOrders promise followed by addProd.

Comment: It won't work. Only first file is added. I suppose because of returning new promise.

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I managed to add custom wait(). Every time file is added to contaioner, remove icon is showed. So I ended up creating:

```js
wait(){
  const ec = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  var removeFileButton= element(by.id('trash-can'));
  browser.wait(ec.elementToBeClickable(removeFileButton), 3000);
}
```

And it works!!!